# Create lambda function which calculates factorial recursively

Tags: java, recursion, kotlin

Can someone create lambda function which returns factorial recursively?

Comment: Hi! It would be easier to get answers with good quetions. Check the guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Mate, turn to the [help] to learn how and what to ask here.

Answer (score 2):

Lambda is a type of **"Name Less"** function like in Java we have **Anonymous** function.
Thus if you don't have a name, you cannot call itself.

Moreover Lambda are usually used with **Iterable** objects like Array in **Kotlin**.

Thus we **cannot** write any recursive Lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas can't call themselves, so it's not easily doable. You can create the usual named function and call it recursively by name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is a good practice, but in Kotlin you can as well inheritance from lambdas, cause lambdas in Kotlin are just wrappers for such types as Function1 and so on. The following code will behave itself as a lambda:

```
class FactorialLambda : (Int) -> Int {
    override fun invoke(n: Int): Int =
        if (n == 0 || n == 1)
            1;
        else
            n * this(n - 1);
}

fun main() {
    val factorialLambda = FactorialLambda()
    print(factorialLambda(0))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the lambda as a `lateinit` and reference itself inside the lambda when declaring it. With this approach it cannot be a toplevel lambda, but you can use it inside the body of another function or declare the lambda in the init block of class:

```
lateinit var f: (Int) -> Int
f = {
    if (it <= 1) 1
    else it * f(it - 1)
}
```